# Cómo puedo hacer un filtro de busqueda en React Native?

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native, axios, busqueda

Como puedo hacer para que este input filtre los datos de busqueda desde esta api http://mobileapi.lbby.online/api/Contactos/ObtenerListado

```
<Input placeholder="Buscar" onChangeText={text => this.searchFilterFunction(text)}/>


searchFilterFunction = text => {
    this.setState({
      value: text,
    });

    const newData = this.state.Items.filter(item => {
      const itemData = `${item.NombreCompleto.toUpperCase()} ${item.CorreoElectronico.toUpperCase()} ${item.Id}`;
      const textData = text.toUpperCase();

      return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
    });
    this.setState({
        Items: newData,
    });
};
```

Tengo un bug al no tener nada escrito no me manda ningun array, en lugar de mandarmelos todos

Comment: Puedes poner lo que intentastes?

Comment: la logica es sencilla pon una lista debajo del input , en react native seria elevation en android y z index en ios, para ponerlos encima de otro el orden. cada vez que se acutalize buscas los datos y los muestras en una lista debajo del input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la propiedad filter de los array de JavaScript para crear tu propio buscador te dejo un ejemplo.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp

Si no te quieres complicar la vida puedes usar un packages que ya lleve el sistema de filtro y reutilizarlo como es el siguiente.
https://yarnpkg.com/package/react-search-input

Comment: Lo hice con el filter pero tengo un bug mira este es mi codigo 

searchFilterFunction = text => {
        this.setState({
          value: text,
        });
    
        const newData = this.state.Items.filter(item => {
          const itemData = `${item.NombreCompleto.toUpperCase()} ${item.CorreoElectronico.toUpperCase()} ${item.Id}`;
          const textData = text.toUpperCase();
    
          return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
        });
        this.setState({
            Items: newData,
        });
    };